# Ubuntu is not detecting my LCD properly , how do I fix the problem?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, lcd

I want to reduce the brightness of my monitor as per my wish .
But ubuntu System->Prefernce->Monitor doesn't have options and I think that coz it uses generic drivers . How do I fix this problem ?

Model is Acer One Zg5 , Ubuntu 10.10 OS . Do I load the LCD driver ? I think it has a intel based inbuilt GFX card .

/proc/acpi/video/OVGA/LCD$ cat *


device_id:    0x0400
type:         UNKNOWN
known by bios: no
state:     0x1d
query:     0x00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you exec `$ cat /proc/acpi/video/DGFX/LCD/brightness` ?
Do you have any brightness dev file in your `/proc/acpi/video/OVGA`? If yes, then try to adjust that value using `echo 100 > /proc/acpi/video/DGFX/LCD/brightness` else put a comment… ;)

Comment: Using pastebin as its clunky format : http://paste.pound-python.org/show/4087/

Comment: Not sure what this means...?